# Bash script to append argument to $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, path, environment-variables

I'm trying to write as simple a bash script as possible to append one argument to the $PATH environment variable if argument isn't already part of the $PATH. I know there are other simple ways to do it by not using a bash script; however, I want to use a bash script. I've experimented with `export` but I haven't had any luck. Right now my simple code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$(echo $PATH)" != *"$1"* ]]
then
PATH=$PATH:$1
fi
```

But:

```
$ ./script /home/scripts
$ echo $PATH
(returns unaltered PATH)
```

Answer (score 2):

try with src or .:

`src ./script /home/scripts
. ./script /home/scripts`

It's because your script runs on its own interpreter and this interpreter instance (which is where the variable $PATH is getting set) dies when the script dies. You have to ask your *current* interpreter to run the script instead (that's what src or **.** are used for)

Comment: I was looking at the `if` logic and completely overlooked this. For what it's worth, this `if` logic is probably better: `if [ -d "$1" ] && ! echo $PATH | grep -E -q "(^|:)$1($|:)"`

Comment: In case someone reading that finds the regular expression hard to parse, it is specifically looking for the `$1` that is passed in with a `:` before and after it, or at the very start or the very end of the `$PATH` variable. So, for instance, if `/bin/too` is already in the path, you can still add `/bin` to the path, which you can't do if you don't require the delimeters.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. That's a great point.
Is there a way to do this task with actually calling the command and not sourcing it?

Comment: I use this: `[[ -d "$HOME/.cargo/bin" && ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.cargo/bin:"* ]] && export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"` (well, it's a prepend example, you can put the new location on the end to append)  The logic is "if the directory exists, and it's not already in PATH, then add it to PATH."  Makes re-source-ing the file safe.